# PHP For loop to count amount of rows in table and then update a column value using MySQL

Tags: php, jquery

In my form I have a table that is populated using MySQLi. Under the table there is a button that will call an AJAX script which will run my test.php file. This is where I need the for loop. I have 2 values being echo'd. Dotime (which needs to be updated in the database) and taskID which I need for the query.

jQuery code here:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

$('#UpdateTable').click(function()
{
    getdata();
}); 

function getdata()
{
    console.log($('#UpdateForm').serialize());

    $.ajax(
    {
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'test.php',
    data: $('#UpdateForm').serialize(),
    
    succes: function(data) 
    {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function() 
    {
        alert("Something went wrong")
    }
    });
}

});
```

Test.php code:

```
<?php 
$Time = $_POST['DoTime'];
$TaskID = $_POST['ID'];

echo $TaskID;
echo $Time;

?>
```

This is my table and the console output when I click update

[image]

What I need to know is how do I build a For loop that will count my rows and then will update 1 value to the database using the data that shows up in the console.

Note: I am very bad in PHP, I can do the basics but more advanced stuff like this I can't do properly.

Answer (score 0):

Why count with a for loop? Can't you use the mysql count function?

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp

(May i missunderstood your question... so sorry if this don't help.)

Comment: For example, in the picture i have 3 rows AKA 3x the values Dotime and 3x the value TaskID. So for row 1 Dotime = 00:50:38 & TaskID = 1. I need these values to be updated to the database. But i need all the rows not only row 1.

Comment: Okay... i try to understand you.

Step by step:

1: You need to update some values in your database? Just do it. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp
Use where Conditions to select the correct entry of your databse. 

2: "But i need all the rows not only row 1" ... where do you need those rows? Sorry, i really don't understand, but i try to help x: 
May there is someone else understanding your problem bether than me...

Comment: I know how to use queries, but i need a php loop to fetch values from the rows and then updating the task with those values. This has to be dynamic thats why i have to count the rows that are in the table. The already build the query:  UPDATE `workbreakdown`.`tasks` SET  `Do` = '00:04:24' WHERE `ID` = 7;

Comment: Okay, so as i said, use mysql count function for your dynamic part. A second time the URL for reference:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp

For more i really can't help you. I'm really sorry, but i don't understand you. As far as i can, i would interpret your problem as "I want to fetch values from database and then update my tasks (which one are also in de db?!) with those values." So i don't understand what you want to update with what. Sorry

Comment: Im not fetching them from the database im fetching them from the table. The timer adds up and that is the value i need to update in the database. But its fine :)